# How to secure WCF service which an Android app will use?

Tags: wcf, ssl

How to secure WCF service which an Android app will use?

Currently we are building an android app that will connect(by using SOAP) with a WCF service (made on another pc in console host)...

We actually want to secure this server so only people with right credentials can access the app?

How do we do this??? Do we need to use transport or message security... And can transport only use SSL or not??

And also is it better to use IIS for this or not..

Please help

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by configuring everything to use HTTPS (i.e., HTTP over SSL) so that your communication channels are encrypted. Then add some sort of login credential scheme so that clients authenticate to the server. The simplest is username and password. You can use Basic or Digest auth styles; both should be supported by both ends so the choice is up to you (and it's not so important which you choose since it is all inside HTTPS anyway).

All this is independent of which clients you use and which servers you use. (There's also various XML Security things that you can use with SOAP, but that's adding a *lot* more complexity for very little extra advantage; the big gain comes from going to HTTPS.)

Comment: If i want user login with basic auth style how do i do this is there any tutorial on the web(simple) im struggling for hours..